# Can egg be scrambled inside shell?

Tags: eggs

Is there a way to scramble an egg inside its shell without using an external dish? E.g. delicately puncture the shell with a needle of sorts, penetrate the yolk and shake it while keeping the hole plugged with a finger.

I have a favorite Asian soup that I like to twist with a dropped egg at the time of reheating. I do go out camping a lot and it would be nice to spare a dish while fixing the soup on the tailgate of my truck.

Alternatively, is it viable to drop an unscrambled egg in the soup and scramble it in the short amount of time before it cooks?

Comment: Never tried it, but apparently by spinning the egg very quickly, you can get it to scramble. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKCkR6L85vg
Search youtube for more videos of "how to scramble egg in shell"

Comment: There is an actual gadget to do this. I forget where I saw it. Alternatively. crack the egg into the soup before it's warm, scramble your egg, and let it cook in the soup.

Comment: One method that might solve the problem - drop the egg in your serving bowl, beat a little, then pour the hot soup on top of it.  It will cook in the residual heat.  I've used this for soups pretty successfully.  (if you want just one egg for the whole pot, you can pour the bowlful back, mix well, and re-serve to your bowl).